# Change option content with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Following my code:

```
<select>
   <option value="1">Test</option>
   <option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

How to change with pure javascript cross browser the first "Test" and the second "Test2"?

Comment: Change only the text or multiple attributes?

Comment: @Thew Why do some people suggest jQuery even for the smallest use cases one can imagine? Using pure JavaScript is neither bad nor naive.

Comment: @Thew That question is about selecting an option with jQuery, not changing the text of the option.

Comment: What's the problem? Find the element, then set its `innerHTML` property to what you want.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, understood it wrong. I'm sorry.

Comment: @ComFreek Because they don't know how to do it with vanilla.

Comment: @ComFreek Haha, read the most upvoted comment on the 1st answer on that question.

Comment: @Thew Hmm that doesn't convince me. Take a look at [this image](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) ;) I don't want to blame jQuery, it's fine if you're already using it. **But** embedding it for the single purpose of changing an option's text is an overkill.

Comment: @ComFreek Haha, had a laugh ;) I'm just using jQuery for easier AJAX writing and animations, I'd like to see someone do that without jQuery

Comment: everybody Why I'm getting downvote please check my answer.

Comment: @ComFreek That is the best image ever ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="myOptions">
   <option value="1">Test</option>
   <option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById('myOptions').options[0].innerHTML = "New Text";
    document.getElementById('myOptions').options[1].innerHTML = "New Text 2";

}

change();
```

Also, here's a demo you use to verify:

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/kBd79/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `options` from the `select` element (I gave your select an ID of `someSelect` for this demo:

```
function alterSelect() {
    var select = document.getElementById("someSelect");
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        select.options[i].text = "New stuff " + i;
    }
}
```

This will replace each option text with: New stuff *number* -- where *number* is the iteration number of the for-loop. See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/4PyGC/

Answer (score -1):

You can just change the innerHTML of the `<option>` tag